# What cause error 404 "page is not found" in mobile phone but found in desktop computer?

Tags: php, html, mobile, amp-html

I've just moved from old hosting to a new hosting and also I move the domain registrar to this new hosting.

My desktop version website index.html has an alternate link to index.html AMP-version which resides inside `public_html/mobile/` folder.
It works correctly before I move to the new hosting.

After I move to the new hosting, I change the amp version by adding a horizontal navbar. So, this version resides in the new hosting server (`public_html/mobile/`). The old hosting server still has the old amp version which is without horizontal navbar.

The problem is :
If in DESKTOP Chrome browser "inspection console" (so it looks like a mobile phone in the desktop browser) and I type the address of my website ---> `blablabla.com`, the result is correct - it show me the mobile version with that horizontal navbar. So it did go to the alternate address : `blablabla.com/mobile/`which now a new domain registrar and a new hosting company.

However, if in MOBILE Chrome browser I type the address of my website `blablabla.com`, it also go to the alternate address : `blablabla.com/mobile/` BUT the result show me the old mobile version - there is no horizontal navbar.

It seems somewhere in the net, Google has a "memory" for the mobile version which in this case it's still the old version in Google's memory.

The other thing which I do today :

1. upload a new abcde.**php** file to `public_html/` folder of the new hosting server
2. upload a new abcde.**html** AMP version file to `public_html/mobile/` folder of the new hosting server

Now when I go to this address:
If in DESKTOP Chrome browser "inspection console" (so it looks like a mobile phone) and I type the address ---> `blablabla.com/abcde.php`, the result is correct - it show me the mobile version and the address bar automatically change to `blablabla.com/mobile/abcde.html`.

and again, if in MOBILE Chrome browser, after I type the address `blablabla.com/abcde.php`, it also go to the alternate address : `blablabla.com/mobile/abcde.html` BUT it show me error 404 not found.

So this time, it seems it's because Google's memory for my mobile version doesn't have the abcde.html file yet, that's why the result say error 404 not found for `blablabla.com/mobile/abcde.html` although actually the file is there in the new hosting server.

Anyway, that's only my guessing.
So, what actually is the cause the result for the address show 404 error file not found if using mobile phone, but it find the file if using the computer ?

Comment: Did you try updating AMP cache? https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache

Comment: @PLW .... No, just know it from your comment. I will try it now and report it to you. Report : sad... I think I won't be able to update the cache, since in the link you give it say : _"The URL must be HTTPS"_. My URL is http. Thank you PLW.

Comment: Neither cache nor validation will work unless origin is HTTPS.

Comment: @JayGray, that's new. And that means this https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/basic_markup/ link is outdated since that link still say it doesn't have to be HTTPS ---> _"Although, HTTPS is not required for the AMP document itself or for images and fonts"_. And that means amp analyzer don't work properly since **my amp page is recognize as a valid amp, show in the search result with "flash" icon although my website is HTTP**. As long as I know until today, if the amp-page only contain text and image then it's valid.

Comment: OK, perhaps a simple page is valid. We use several amp features that require HTTPS (the validator generates errors if the page is not HTTPS). And if the page is invalid, a number of error messages ensue. Can you host the page on heroku (https://www.heroku.com/)? Then you can eliminate the HTTPS issue and repeat your above analysis process.

Comment: Yes, my amp page is a simple page, contains only text and image (amp-img tag). That's why maybe the validator not generate error although my domain is in http. Thank you for your explanation, JayGray.